# Run termbox-go app in GoLand's console

Tags: debugging, go, console-application, goland

I want to create a Go app with a console UI using the termui library (which is built on top of the termbox-go library). I can build the app and run it from the command line, but it will not start inside the GoLand IDE (2018.1.3) on Windows 10.

It fails during the termbox-go init when calling `syscall.Syscall` with `SetConsoleScreenBufferSize` parameter. The size for the screen buffer is 80x25. Error message is just "The parameter is incorrect."

How can I debug a termbox-go app in the GoLand or other IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the way to solve this is to build your executable with Go 1.10 or newer, compile it with the following flags: `-gcflags="all=-N -l"` (these are very important and will allow the debugger to work a lot better, and then use the `Run | Attach to Local Process...` option from GoLand and attach to the local process.

I'll see if I can replicate the bug and update this accordingly.

Comment: This works nice. I had to run command `go get gops` to get the option to attach to a local process. Goland showed that option automatically after I tried to attach :) Still it would be nice to have an option to run this directly inside Goland. I will wait for other answers and if nothing better shows-up I will accept your answer. Thanks.

Comment: The builtin terminal is not a PTY one, which means it won't work 100% as a real terminal, that's why there are no other alternatives for this. If I can replicate this and figure out a different way, I'll update the answer as mentioned.

Comment: Funny thing is that it runs inside the Goland's terminal, it just does not run inside the Goland's "run console". I can manually start the app from the Goland's terminal and then attach to it.

Comment: Can you please tell me a way to replicate this?

Comment: Oh, I am sorry. I was so happy with your solution that then I got confused with my other attempts. I am just able to run the app inside the Goland's terminal but I am not able to attach to it :( Sorry.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really know what to make of this. Is this solved or not? If not, please open an issue at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/Go and I'll be happy to help. Provide a way to replicate this, with which steps I need to take, and eventually the code, if possible. Thank you.

Comment: I just tried it and it is possible to run a termui from Goland's terminal and attach it's debugger to it and step through code. Here is a screenshot from Windows 10 with a termui app paused at a breakpoint. https://www.dropbox.com/s/6gszx7dcm1pzxd7/goland_debug_termbox.png